# Как сделать закрытие окна при нажатии на пустую область за пределами окна?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function OpenNav_CreateAccount() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "50%";
    }

    /* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function CloseNav_CreateAccount() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }

for (var i=2011; i >= 1930; i--)
{
    let last_option = document.getElementById("year_selection_register_form");

    last_option.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<option>'+String(i)+'</option>');
}
```

```css
 .overlay-profile-homepage {   
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    background-color: rgb(247, 106, 25) ; /* Black fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(247, 106, 25, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
    bottom:0; /* добавили */
  }
  
  
  .overlay-content-profile-homepage {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%; /* 100% width */
    text-align: center; /* Centered text/links */
  }
  
  .overlay-profile-homepage a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block; /* Display block instead of inline */
    transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
  }

  .overlay-profile-homepage a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  

  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
    .overlay .closebtn {
      font-size: 40px;
      top: 15px;
      right: 35px;
    }
  }
```

```html
  .overlay {
              /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */
              height: 100%;
              width: 0;
              position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
              z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
              left: 0;
              top: 0;
              background-color: rgb(247, 106, 25) ; /* Black fallback color */
              background-color: rgba(247, 106, 25, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
              backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
              overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
              transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
            }
          
            /* Position the content inside the overlay */
            .overlay-content {
              position: relative;
              top: 20%; /* 25% from the top */
              width: 80%; /* 100% width */
              text-align: right; /* Centered text/links */
              margin-top: 30px; /* 30px top margin to avoid conflict with the close button on smaller screens */
              margin-left:7%;
            }
          
            /* The navigation links inside the overlay */
            .overlay a {
              padding: 8px;
              text-decoration: none;
              font-size: 36px;
              color: #818181;
              display: block; /* Display block instead of inline */
              transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
            }
          
            /* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
            .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
              color: #f1f1f1;
            }
          
            /* Position the close button (top right corner) */
            .overlay .closebtn {
              position: absolute;
              color:#ffffff;
              top: 20px;
              right: 45px;
              font-size: 60px;
            }
          
            /* When the height of the screen is less than 450 pixels, change the font-size of the links and position the close button again, so they don't overlap */
            @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
              .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
              .overlay .closebtn {
                font-size: 40px;
                top: 15px;
                right: 35px;
              }
            }
          </style>
```

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+вне+окна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+вне+окна)  - поиск, он существует))

Comment: Смотрел, не смог применить уже готовые решения, к своему примеру(